# Chrome Dev Tools. Не удается исключить из отладки js файлы плагинов. Как заставить работать параметр Blackbox content scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

При пошаговой откладке js файлов проекта в Chrome Dev Tools регулярно попадаю в js файлы хромовских плагинов.

В офиц. доках есть решение: [Blackbox Chrome Extension Scripts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/guides/blackbox-chrome-extension-scripts)

Но при включении этого параметра:
[image]

Все равно при отладке попадаю в файлы плагинов.
[image]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Еще один способ: на строчке где включается дебаггер нажать правкой кнопкой мыши и выбрать "Never pause here"